# Creating Numpy array or variable length arrays

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I want to create a Numpy array or arrays, where each sub array has the shape  [128, audio_length, 1], so I can feed this np array into Keras.fit. However I cannot seem to figure out how to do this as np.array just throws cannot broadcast error

```
def prepare_data(df, config, data_dir, bands=128):
    log_specgrams_2048 = []
    for i, fname in enumerate(df.index):
        file_path = data_dir + fname
        data, _ = librosa.core.load(file_path, sr=config.sampling_rate, res_type="kaiser_fast")
        melspec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(data, sr=config.sampling_rate, n_mels=bands)
        logspec = librosa.core.power_to_db(melspec)  # shape would be [128, your_audio_length]
        logspec = logspec[..., np.newaxis]  # shape will be [128, your_audio_length, 1]
        log_specgrams_2048.append(normalize_data(logspec))
    return log_specgrams_2048
```

Comment: Which `np.array` call throws this error?  I don't see one in your code.  Do you know for sure that `Keras.fit` will work with an object dtype array containing arrays of varying size?

Comment: Hi  hpaulj, when i try and convert the `log_specgrams_2048` to an np it throws the error then. I think that Keras will work with varying input size as I've built an FCN where the input is `inp = Input(shape=(None, None, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You have to group sequences by length and call Keras.fit multiple times.

You can do:

- Bucketing
- Zero-padding
- Batch of size 1

Comment: Hi Neabfi, thank you for you answer. I was hoping you might be able to give me an example of Batch of size 1 and Bucketing